# open file from ajax responce in mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to open file from Ajax response. here is the code. Here Ajax call response contain PDF file.

I want to open file in new tab of browser.here i am using mvc framework.

```
function ViewPDF(key){
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OpenDocument", "DocumentApproveUser")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { "key": key},
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(data);
                window.open(data);
                if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Forcefullylogin") == "true") {
                    var url = "/Login/Login";
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
                else {
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#divLoading").hide();
                if (error.getResponseHeader("Forcefullylogin") == true") {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Login")';
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
                else {
                    alert('Something went wrong in system.Please try again later!or contact to system administrator.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Code :
see below is code of my controller. this code return pdf file as ajax response.
I want to open that response in my browser.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OpenDocument(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            int Id = 0;
            try
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
                string decodedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(decodedString)))
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(decodedString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorName = "An error occured while opening document.";
                base.ErrorLogger.Error("***OpenDocument***", ex);
                return null;
            }
            DocumentApproveViewModel vm = new DocumentApproveViewModel();
            vm.DocumentsApprovalModel = DocumentApproveViewModel.GetDocTransactionModelList(_repo.GetAll());
            DocumentApprovalModel lst;

            lst = (from x in vm.DocumentsApprovalModel where x.Id.Equals(Id) select x).FirstOrDefault();
            base.Logger.InfoFormat("User : '{0}' going to access pdf document at {1} ", SessionFactory.CurrentUser.Name, System.DateTime.Now);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ICollection<PasswordManagementViewModel> passwordList = null;
            PasswordManagementViewModel password = null;
            passwordList = PasswordManagementViewModel.GetSystemEncryptionKeyList(_encryption.GetAll());
            password = passwordList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDateTime).FirstOrDefault();
            string decryptPassword = Base64EncodeDecode.Decrypt(password.EncryptionKey, true);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Inhariting Logic from PDFSharpUtil Class.
            byte[] PdfFileByte = _docSecurity.OpenPdfFile(lst.File, decryptPassword, SessionFactory.CurrentUser.EncryptionKey, SessionFactory.CurrentUser.Name, lst.DocumentTransactionName, false, SessionFactory.PdfViewCount);

            /// Added logic for adding data into Document History ///
            DocumentHistory objDocumentHistory = new DocumentHistory();
            objDocumentHistory.SentTo = null;
            objDocumentHistory.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            objDocumentHistory.ActionPerformedBy = SessionFactory.CurrentUser.Id;
            objDocumentHistory.Action = EDocumentAction.View;
            objDocumentHistory.DocumentId = Id;
            _docHistoryRepo.Add(objDocumentHistory);
            //Increment view count not to ask password from second attempt to open PDF file
            SessionFactory.PdfViewCount++;
            return File(PdfFileByte, "application/pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorName = "An error occured while opening Document";
            base.ErrorLogger.Error("***OpenDocument :: DocumentView***", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the server code too ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: What does the `OpenDocument` method returns ? Why are you making the ajax call ? If you know the url of the file at client side, simply use `window.location.herf=thatUrl;`

Comment: see above i have shared server side code also.

Comment: does your code ask the user if they want to save the file (or, depending on the browser settings, just automatically save it to the download folder)? I don't think ajax is the correct way to be doing this. Just open a new window which calls the OpenDocument method (via a GET, which you'll need to enable) directly, and then it will display the file, assuming the user has a PDF viewer installed in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to use ajax to download file. Just open the url in a new browser tab. Based on your browser settings, it will either open in the tab or ask whether you want to save it.

You can set the new url to `window.location.href`

```
function ViewPDF(key)
{
   var  url= '@Url.Action("OpenDocument", "DocumentApproveUser")?key='+key,
   window.location.href = url;
}
```

Based on the browser setting, the above 2 approaches will either ask user whether he wishes to download or open the file or simply download/open the file. If you prefer to show the file content directly in the browser, you may send a filestream to the browser.

Here is a quick example, which reads the pdf from a disk in the Contents/Downloads directory in app root and return the file stream.

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    var pathToTheFile=Server.MapPath("~/Content/Downloads/sampleFile.pdf");
    var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToTheFile,
                                        FileMode.Open,
                                        FileAccess.Read
                                    );
    return  new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");           
}
```